# Improving performance of a function in python

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I have a text file fo several GB with this format

```
0 274 593869.99 6734999.96 121.83 1,
0 273 593869.51 6734999.92 121.57 1,
0 273 593869.15 6734999.89 121.57 1,
0 273 593868.79 6734999.86 121.65 1,
0 273 593868.44 6734999.84 121.65 1,
0 273 593869.00 6734999.94 124.21 1,
0 273 593868.68 6734999.92 124.32 1,
0 273 593868.39 6734999.90 124.44 1,
0 273 593866.94 6734999.71 121.37 1,
0 273 593868.73 6734999.99 127.28 1,
```

I have a simple function to filter in Python 2.7 on Windows. The function reads the entire file, selects the line with the same `idtile` (first and second column) and returns the list of points (x,y,z, and label) and the `idtile`.

```
tiles_id = [j for j in np.ndindex(ny, nx)] #ny = number of row, nx= number of columns
idtile = tiles_id[0]

def file_filter(name,idtile):
        lst = []
        for line in file(name, mode="r"):
            element = line.split() # add value
            if (int(element[0]),int(element[1])) == idtile:
                lst.append(element[2:])
                dy, dx = int(element[0]),int(element[1])
        return(lst, dy, dx)
```

The file is more than 32 GB and the bottle-neck is the reading of the file. I am looking for some suggestions or examples in order to speed up my function (ex: Parallel computing or other approaches).

My solution is to split the text file into tiles (using x and y location). The solution is not elegant and I am looking for an efficient approach.

Comment: Can you split the file? If you can you may be able to achieve something with a parallel approach, otherwise it's unlikely that will be of help. Also, even then, you'd have to be on an SSD for it to help as hard drives are fastest at linear reads not seeking around

Comment: @entropy. I did. I splited the file in tiles but my solution it's not elegant. I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: How many times is `file_filter()` being called in your program?

Comment: If you want to read this file many times, how about giving the job to a database?

Comment: @Ber suppose lts_idtile is a list of idtile, the file_filter() is calling each time for len(lts_idtile).

Comment: @eumiro, i don't know a database approach.

Comment: @Gianni: the rough idea would be to use *SQL with idx, idy, x, y, z and whatever the '1' is named. the database stores the data "effiently" for repeated retrievals of values, eg something like `SELECT * FROM vals WHERE idx = 0 AND idy = 273`. add the 'power' of an 'index' to that and you have groked yourself another solution.

Comment: How many unique idtile? I suggest you split the text file to many small text files that the filename is the idtile, the content is all the rows that startswiths idtile. If the count of idtile is large, you can use `hash(idtile) % N` as the file name.

Comment: dear @akira the file is really huge (more than 32 GB). Is It possible store the data?

Comment: dear @Gianni: 32gb of whatever fits onto the little stick that sits within the camera i use to take useless pictures of sun flowers.

Comment: Dear @HYRY about split the text file to many small text files using the idtile. The only approach i can think is reading len(lts_idtile) times the text file and save len(lts_idtile) times. Do you have a good approach to split efficientely the text file?

Comment: Dear @akira i wish to see your sun flowers (i came from Tuscany). Could i ask an example about your approach please?

Comment: dear @BurhanKhalid. No, this is the problem.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, probably after a 2 million of lines 0 274 return

Comment: I am a little bit naive on python .                               But as a start  mid pos = filesize/2     . Start one of ur operations from byte 0 of the file to the mid and the second operation from mid+1 to the end .  U could decide on the number of chunks of bytes u wish to operate per operation . But I am not sure whether locking is required .

Comment: for every idtile in the lts_idtile you need to open the file with the name idtile and read it's content. So I suggest you split the large text file into many small binary files, and the content of the binary file can be load by `numpy.fromfile()`.

Comment: @sameerkarjatkar If the process is I/O bound that wouldn't help as you'd still read only as fast as the drive could serve you the file

Comment: I am going to measure times for several of the solutions... Will modify my answer when done.

Comment: Reading file is not a bottleneck! Measured times, file input takes some 10% out of the whole execution time.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change your code so that you read the big file once and write (temporary) files for each tile id. Something like:

```
def create_files(name, idtiles=None):
    files = {}
    for line in open(name):
         elements = line.split()
         idtile = (int(elements[0]), int(elements[1]))
         if idtiles is not None and idtile not in idtiles:
             continue
         if idtile not in files:
             files[idtile] = open("tempfile_{}_{}".format(elements[0], elements[1]), "w")
         print >>files[idtile], line
    for f in files.itervalues():
        f.close()
    return files
```

`create_files()` will return a `{(tilex, tiley): fileobject}` dictionary.

A variant that closes the files after writing each line, to work around the "Too many open files" error. This variant returns a `{(tilex, tiley: filename}` dictionary. Will probably be a bit slower.

```
def create_files(name, idtiles=None):
    files = {}
    for line in open(name):
         elements = line.split()
         idtile = (int(elements[0]), int(elements[1]))
         if idtiles is not None and idtile not in idtiles:
             continue
         filename = "tempfile_{}_{}".format(elements[0], elements[1])
         files[idtile] = filename
         with open(filename, "a") as f:
             print >>f, line
    return files
```

Comment: so, you split the large files into smaller files .. something OP did already if i am not mislead.

Comment: @codeape. Return this error message
create_files(name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<editor selection>", line 9, in create_files
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'tempfile_3_340'

Comment: Updated with variant that closes the files after each written line.

Comment: @codeape Does the name file be sorted? your code need to be a lit be fixed

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the last question. I haven't tested the code, so yes, it might need some fixing. Nothing needs to be sorted I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'idtile's appear to be in a certain order. That is, the sample data suggests that once you traverse through a certain 'idtile' and hit the next, there is no chance that a line with that 'idtile' will show up again. If this is the case, you may break the `for` loop once you finish dealing with the 'idtile' you want and hit a different one. Off the top of my head:

```
loopkiller = false
for line in file(name, mode="r"):
    element = line.split()
    if (int(element[0]),int(element[1])) == idtile:
        lst.append(element[2:])
        dy, dx = int(element[0]),int(element[1])
        loopkiller = true
    elif loopkiller:
        break;
```

This way, once you are done with a certain 'idtile', you stop; whereas in your example, you keep on reading until the end of the file.

If your idtiles appear in a random order, maybe you could try writing an ordered version of your file first.

Also, evaluating the digits of your idtiles seperately may help you traverse the file faster. Supposing your `idtile` is a two-tuple of one-digit and three-digit integers, perhaps something along the lines of:

```
for line in file(name, mode="r"):
    element = line.split()
    if int(element[0][0]) == idtile[0]:
        if element[1][0] == str(idtile[1])[0]:
            if element[1][1] == str(idtile[1])[1]:
                if element[1][2] == str(idtile[1])[2]:
                    dy, dx = int(element[0]),int(element[1])
                else go_forward(walk)
            else go_forward(run)
         else go_forward(sprint)
     else go_forward(warp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Major rule of speed: Do less.

- You could create a sorted version of `huge.txt` and keep track of the positions of the `idtitle`. So, if you search for (223872, 23239) you know already at which position in the file the given information is and could skip everything before (`file.seek`). One might argue that this information is somewhat equal to an ['INDEX'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index#Computer_science).
- You could use `mmap` to mmap the file into the ram.
- You can start writing 'workers' to work on different files / positions
- You could transfer the given file into something like a SQL-server and use standard SQL to retrieve the data. Yes, transfering the 32gigs of data into the database takes time, but consider it as a kind of preprocessing. After that the database will use whatever means to access the data faster than your approach.

Minor thoughts:

- You could work with slices instead of `line.split()` to avoid lots of tiny memory allocations.

Outline of how to use a Database:

Assume you have something like `PostgreSQL` around:

```
CREATE TABLE tiles
(
  tile_x integer,
  tile_y integer,
  x double precision,
  y double precision,
  z double precision,
  flag integer
);
```

Then you could replace all whitespaces in the input file with `|` and all the `,` with  (to create a nice and shiney `.csv`) and feed that directly into the database:

```
 COPY "tiles" from "\full\path\to\huge.txt" WITH DELIMITER "|";
```

You can then do fancy stuff like this:

```
SELECT * FROM "tiles";

tile_x | tile_y |     x     |     y      |   z    | flag
-------+--------+-----------+------------+--------+-----
     0 |    274 | 593869.99 | 6734999.96 | 121.83 |    1
     0 |    273 | 593869.51 | 6734999.92 | 121.57 |    1
     0 |    273 | 593869.15 | 6734999.89 | 121.57 |    1
     0 |    273 | 593868.79 | 6734999.86 | 121.65 |    1
     0 |    273 | 593868.44 | 6734999.84 | 121.65 |    1
     0 |    273 |    593869 | 6734999.94 | 124.21 |    1
     0 |    273 | 593868.68 | 6734999.92 | 124.32 |    1
     0 |    273 | 593868.39 |  6734999.9 | 124.44 |    1
     0 |    273 | 593866.94 | 6734999.71 | 121.37 |    1
     0 |    273 | 593868.73 | 6734999.99 | 127.28 |    1
```

Or something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM "tiles" WHERE tile_y > 273;

tile_x | tile_y |     x     |     y      |   z    | flag
-------+--------+-----------+------------+--------+-----
     0 |    274 | 593869.99 | 6734999.96 | 121.83 |    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert you filter to a generator function:

```
def file_filter(name):
        lst = []
        idtile = None
        for line in file(name, mode="r"):
            element = line.split() # add value
            if idtile is None:
               idtile = (int(element[0]), int(element[1]))
            if (int(element[0]), int(element[1])) == idtile:
                lst.append(element[2:])
                dy, dx = int(element[0]),int(element[1])
            else:
                yield lst, dx, dy
                lst = []
                idtile = None
```

This function should return one tuple of `list_of_data, dx, dy` for each idtile, provided that the file is sorted on idtile

New you can use it like this:

```
for lst, dx, dy in file_filter('you_name_it'):
    process_tile_data(lst, dx, dy)
```

Comment: Thanks Ber. I skip the second step after file_filter(name), sorry

Comment: Thanks @Ber. I will work how to sort (from 0,0 to ...) the file.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to compare the times used for your full reading procedure and for just reading lines and doing nothing to them. If those times are close, the only thing you can really do is to change approach (splitting your files etc.), for what you can probably optimize is data processing time, not file reading time.

I also see two moments in your code that are worth fixing:

```
with open(name) as f:
    for line in f:
        pass #Here goes the loop body
```

1. Use `with` to explicitly close your file. Your solution should work in CPython, but that depends on implementation and may not be that effective always.
2. You perform transformation of a string to `int` twice. It is a relatively slow operation. Remove the second one by reusing the result.

P.S. It looks like an array of depth or height values for a set of points on Earth surface, and the surface is split in tiles. :-)

Comment: Thank ellioh. Suggestions to improve are always welcome. Why with open(name) as f: instead of  for line in open(name):?

Comment: Fixed a typo. :-) "for line in f", of course. The "with" statement always closes the file. In your code the file is closed when garbage collector removes file object. In CPython with its reference counting that is almost the same, but other flavors of Python may do that other way, and the file will stay open until the object is garbage collected, maybe much later.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is split the large text file into many small binary file for each idtile. To read the text file faster, you can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
n = 400000 # read n rows as one block
for df in pd.read_table(large_text_file, sep=" ", comment=",", header=None, chunksize=n):
    for key, g in df.groupby([0, 1]):
        fn = "%d_%d.tmp" % key
            with open(fn, "ab") as f:
                data = g.ix[:, 2:5].values
                data.tofile(f)
```

Then you can get content of one binary file by:

```
np.fromfile("0_273.tmp").reshape(-1, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid doing the `split()` and `int()` on every line by doing a string comparison instead:

```
def file_filter(name,idtile):
    lst = []
    id_str = "%d %d " % idtile
    with open(name) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith(id_str):
                element = line.split() # add value
                lst.append(element[2:])
                dy, dx = int(element[0]),int(element[1])
    return(lst, dy, dx)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some statistics. I'm going to update it as more solutions appear. The following program works with a file that consists of repetitions of the lines from the question.

```
import sys

def f0(name, idtile):
    lst = []
    dx, dy = None, None
    with open(name) as f:
        for line in f:
            pass


"""def f0(name, idtile):
    lst = []
    dx, dy = None, None
    with open(name) as f:
        for line in f:
            line.split()"""


def f1(name, idtile):
    lst = []
    dx, dy = None, None
    with open(name) as f:
        for line in f:
            element = line.split() # add value
            if (int(element[0]),int(element[1])) == idtile:
                lst.append(element[2:])
                dy, dx = int(element[0]),int(element[1])
    return(lst, dy, dx)


def f2(name, idtile):
    lst = []
    dx, dy = None, None
    with open(name) as f:
        for line in f:
            element = line.split() # add value
            pdx, pdy = int(element[0]),int(element[1])
            if (pdx, pdy) == idtile:
                lst.append(element[2:])
                dy, dx = pdx, pdy
    return(lst, dy, dx)

def f2(name, idtile):
    lst = []
    dx, dy = None, None
    with open(name) as f:
        for line in f:
            element = line.split() # add value
            pdx, pdy = int(element[0]),int(element[1])
            if (pdx, pdy) == idtile:
                lst.append(element[2:])
                dy, dx = pdx, pdy
    return(lst, dy, dx)


def f3(name,idtile):
    lst = []
    id_str = "%d %d " % idtile
    with open(name) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith(id_str):
                element = line.split() # add value
                lst.append(element[2:])
                dy, dx = int(element[0]),int(element[1])
    return(lst, dy, dx)

functions = [f0, f1, f2, f3]

functions[int(sys.argv[1])]("./srcdata.txt",(0, 273))
```

The shell script for timing is straightforward:

```
#!/bin/sh
time python ./timing.py 0
time python ./timing.py 1
time python ./timing.py 2
```

I prefer to run it that way to avoid previously run functions to have influence on the time of the others.

And the result is:

```
0.02user 0.01system 0:00.03elapsed
0.42user 0.01system 0:00.44elapsed
0.32user 0.02system 0:00.34elapsed
0.33user 0.01system 0:00.35elapsed
```

The good news: **reading file is NOT a bottleneck**, **removing extra transfer to int is effective**.

The bad news: I still do not now how to optimize it significantly.

Comment: reading file is not a bottleneck, the problem is you read the files more than 1 milion of times

Comment: probably i need to sort the file before and slice idtiles by idtiles

Comment: Yes, then it should be sliced. In fact, it's the only way, I think.

Comment: I am open another question on OS. I will put the link if you like to be part

Comment: Yes, at least I would like to have a look.

Comment: posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227254/efficent-way-to-sorting-a-large-text-file-in-python

Comment: In the timings you are looking for `(0, 273)` which is 90 % of the file. I believe @Gianni is trying to extract a very small fraction of the file. Could you re-run the timings using an id that is _not_ in the file? That would be more representative IMO.

Comment: @Janne Karilla, that's true, the problem really is with reading the file once per tile id. However, the problem seems to be solved by splitting the file by tile id's into many files. Follow a link in the previous Gianni's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best and fasted was to solve you problem is using a map reduce algorithm on a (massively) parallel system.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. If you need to do this many times, you obviously need to create some sort of an index. But if this not a frequent activity the best bet would be to multithread it like this.

```
NUMWORKERS = 8
workerlist = []
workQ = Queue.Queue()

def file_filter(name,idtile, numworkers):
    for i in range(NUMWORKERS):
        worker = threading.Thread(target=workerThread, args=(lst,))
    lst = []
    for line in file(name, mode="r"):
        workQ.put(line)                
    for i in range(NUMWORKERS):
        workQ.put(None)
    workQ.join()
    return lst , idtile[0], idtile[1]

def workerThread(lst):
    line = workQ.get()
    if not line:
        return
    element = line.split() # add value
    if (int(element[0]),int(element[1])) == idtile:
        lst.append(element[2:])
```

In case this is a very frequent activity that happens for each idtile then the solution would be drastically different. Doing this for a number of idtiles together will give you best amortized performance. Because any number of idtiles already known can be processed in a single loop over the file.

Comment: This is advantageous because your IO thread is not wasting its time doing computation. Which would mean your IO goes at the maximum possible speed.

Comment: I don't believe this may help. Even more, I would bet this is much slower than doing it in ordinary way, at least in CPython.