# Efficent way to split a large text file in python

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, sorting, optimization

this is a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223749/improving-performance-of-a-function-in-python#comment21464492_15223749) where to improve the time performance of a function in python i need to find an efficient way to split my text file

I have the following text file (more than 32 GB) **not sorted**

```
....................
0 274 593869.99 6734999.96 121.83 1,
0 273 593869.51 6734999.92 121.57 1,
0 273 593869.15 6734999.89 121.57 1,
0 273 593868.79 6734999.86 121.65 1,
0 272 593868.44 6734999.84 121.65 1,
0 273 593869.00 6734999.94 124.21 1,
0 273 593868.68 6734999.92 124.32 1,
0 274 593868.39 6734999.90 124.44 1,
0 275 593866.94 6734999.71 121.37 1,
0 273 593868.73 6734999.99 127.28 1,
.............................
```

the first and second columns are the ID (ex: 0 -273) of location of the x,y,z point in a grid.

```
def point_grid_id(x,y,minx,maxy,distx,disty):
    """give id (row,col)"""
    col = int((x - minx)/distx)
    row = int((maxy - y)/disty)
    return (row, col)
```

the `(minx, maxx)` is the origin of my grid with size `distx,disty`. The the numbers of Id tiles are

```
tiles_id = [j for j in np.ndindex(ny, nx)] #ny = number of row, nx= number of columns 
from [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),...,(ny-1,nx-1)]
n = len(tiles_id)
```

I need to slice the ~32 GB file in `n (= len(tiles_id))` numbers of files.

i can do this without sorting but reading n times the file. For this reason I wish to find an efficient splitting method for the file starting form `(0,0) (=  tiles_id[0])` . After that i can read only one time the splitted files.

Comment: how about not using python?

Comment: Not sure how efficient you can really get with Python for sorting a file of that size.

Comment: Well I hope you've got something to read while it will run, then.

Comment: just free Weekend hiking in the mounts and far from the PC :). I know Python is slow, but if the algorithm takes some days it's ok

Comment: At times I do miss the Big Iron for these JOBs. Those Dinosaurs make you feel that its a cake walk. IBM SORT and the Extension ICETOOL are made for these JOBS. I have also sorted TBs of data effortlessly :-)

Comment: @Gianni: `I LOVE Python!! `, Yeah I can see, LOVE is so blind that you can't see its weakness

Comment: @Abhijit, Love is Love!!! :)

Comment: @Abhijit and Bartek Banachewicz "Life's too short to code in C++" :)

Comment: @Abhijit, personally I see no demonstration of Python weaknesses here, though I admit they really exist. The problem is a good example of a task where performance should be optimized by optimizing algorithms, not the code. And only if the result is still not satisfactory after algorithmic optimizations, there is a serious reason to optimize the code, probably even rewriting it in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorting is hardly possible for a 32GB file, no matter if you use Python or a command line tool (`sort`). Databases seem too powerful, but may be used. However, if you are unwilling to use databases, I would suggest simply splitting the source file in files using the tile id.

You read a line, make a file name out of a tile id and append the line to the file. And continue that until the source file is finished. It is not going to be too fast, but at least it has a complexity of O(N) unlike sorting.

And, of course, individual sorting of files and concatenating them is possible. The main bottleneck in sorting a 32GB file should be memory, not CPU.

Here it is, I think:

```
def temp_file_name(l):
    id0, id1 = l.split()[:2]
    return "tile_%s_%s.tmp" % (id0, id1)

def split_file(name):
    ofiles = {}
    try:
        with open(name) as f:
            for l in f:
                if l:
                    fn = temp_file_name(l)
                    if fn not in ofiles:
                        ofiles[fn] = open(fn, 'w')
                    ofiles[fn].write(l)
    finally:
        for of in ofiles.itervalues():
            of.close()

split_file('srcdata1.txt')
```

But if there is a lot of tiles, more than number of files you can open, you may do so:

```
def split_file(name):
    with open(name) as f:
        for l in f:
            if l:
                fn = temp_file_name(l)
                with open(fn, 'a') as of:
                    of.write(l)
```

And the most perfectionist way is to close some files and remove them from dictionary after reaching a limit on open files number.

Comment: And then you can sort the individual files easily.

Comment: but do i need read only one time?

Comment: Sure it is possible. You'd have to use a multi-file sort and merge, but it's possible.

Comment: Do you really need SORTING? You rather need splitting into tiles, unless I'm wrong. Splitting is easy. But if full sorting is desired, you will be able to sort each file and concatenate them.

Comment: Dear Ellioh and Martijn, Thanks for help your guys are always great. Can be interesting try all solution. Sorting is not required if i can split reading-splitting the file only one time. The sorting idea was an approach to avoid to read the file n=len(tiles_id) times

Comment: @Ellioh, could i ask a code example please. I don't want abuse of your time. (it helps me to study how other people code). thanks

Comment: image the first line is ['451', '35', '592678.75', '6732741.20', '106.20', '1'] and the output file is "tempfile_{}_{}".format(element[0], element[1])
'tempfile_451_35'

Comment: The filename seems ok. Why not?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25609/discussion-between-ellioh-and-gianni)

Comment: @Ellioh i think there is an open connection to close

Comment: @Gianni, do you mean an open file? There should not be. with always closes files. What makes you suspecting that?

Comment: @Ellioh. No just my mistake. Please, could you explain why "if l:"?. Can we skip that line?. Thanks!

Comment: My sample file included an empty line. :-) If yours cannot, you may omit "if l:" safely.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google lead me to [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576755-sorting-big-files-the-python-26-way/) in ActiveState code. It didn;t gave any performance comparison but it seems to do the JOB.

In short, it seems to do what @Ellioh suggested, and you have a ready made recipe and you may not have to reinvent the wheel.